# Autofill (with incrementing row-number) in spreadsheet programs doesn't work as expected

Tags: libreoffice

I have two rows with values and third row must be a difference between first and second row, like here:
3 5  1 . .
2 2  5 . .
1 3 -4 . .
I enter a formula in the 3rd row 2nd column: =$B3-$B4
I enter a formula in the 3rd row 3rd column: =$C3-$C4
And then I (as used in MS excel) select 2 and 3 columns in 3rd row and grab the dot in the bottom right corner, then i pulling it to the right to extend for some columns.
As a result I want to see =$D3-$D4 and =$E3-$E4
But I see only repeating =$B3-$B4, =$C3-$C4, =$B3-$B4, =$C3-$C4, =$B3-$B4, =$C3-$C4.

Tried this in LibreOffice Calc and Gnumeric.
Versions:
LibreOffice 3.3.4 
OOO330m19 (Build:401)
tag libreoffice-3.3.3.1, Ubuntu package 1:3.3.4-0ubuntu1

Gnumeric: 1.10.13

Comment: Isn't this a question for http://ask.libreoffice.org ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, In your question some parts are not clear. But the result is important. So I will give you the answer.

First,

> > I have two rows with values and third row must be a difference between first and second row, like here:
>
> 3 5 1  (first row)
> 2 2 5  (Second Row)
>
> 1 3 -4 (third row)

Now in Libre office calc (or in anyother spread sheet program),if you want to get the result in 3rd row by subtracting from first and second row,your formula doesn't work

> I enter a formula in the 3rd row 2nd column: =$B3-$B4 (here you are subtracting the 3rd row with4th row )
>
> I enter a formula in the 3rd row 3rd column: =$C3-$C4(here you are subtracting the 3rd row with4th row )

so if you want the subtracted result in 3rd row you have to type in 3rd row first column
=A1-A2

in 3rd row second column
=B1-B2

then inorder to move thse formula to the next part of the third row, selct the 3rd row second column,then grab the dot then drag it to the other are of the third column where you want th formula applicble.

There you have it..... you will get

third row must be a difference between first and second row

All the best from RJK

Comment: Thanks. That was easy. I don't know why in the first two cells of third row the formula was with dollar sign. It works, but can't be expanded to other columns of a row.

Comment: sure, you can,select the third row then drag it using the dot. you will get the formula. It worked for me......... (I got the formula transfered to the desired boxes of 3rd row)